# Setup script for Polymer Elements

Tags: python, polymer, setup-project

I created a python web server using Polymer elements for the front-end. 
I was asked to commit my project to svn but leave out all the polymer elements. Instead, I am expected to write a setup script to load all the polymer elements. I installed all the polymer elements with bower but I am confused on how to write this "setup" script. Can anyone point me to the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Commit the bower.json which should include your dependencies and then have a script to run bower install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, exclude your components with `svn propset svn:ignore bower_components .` (in git, this is usually a `.gitignore` file with a `bower_components` line).

Then, ensure your [`bower.json`](http://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/#bowerjson) file has the proper dependencies for all of those components. Then you can commit your code as normal.

Finally, on the production server, after pulling the latest code your setup script should then call `bower install` in the directory containing the `bower.json` file.